# Why I can't send my user data to factory? ng-token-auth

Tags: angularjs, devise

Im using ng-token-auth along with devise-token-auth and I'm going nuts.

After hours struggling to set it up I am having trouble to pass the user (which I logged in) to a factory.

My controller

```
app.controller('sign_in_controller', function($scope, UserData){

 $scope.handleLoginBtnClick = function() {
    $auth.submitLogin($scope.loginForm)
        .then(function(resp) {

    })
        .catch(function(resp) {
    });
};

$scope.$on('auth:login-success', function(ev, user, UserData) {
    console.log(user);
    UserData.addUser(user);   <---Here is where i'm trying to send my user to factory
});

}
```

And my simple Factory>

```
app.factory('UserData', function(){
    var user = {};
    var interfaz = {
        addUser: function(user){
            debugger;
            user = user;
        },
        getUser: function(){
            return user;
        }

    }

    return interfaz;
});
```

And the error I am getting:

ypeError: Cannot read property 'addUser' of undefined

What I'm doing wrong? I tried using $RootScope but I couldn't either...

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are passing `UserData` as a parameter in the callback function.
`UserData` is undefined and so because of that you get the error.
You have injected `UserData` in the controller so just use that:

```
$scope.$on('auth:login-success', function(ev, user) {
    console.log(user);
    UserData.addUser(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your Naming Convention

Copy the below code and test. This should Work

```
  app.factory('UserData', function(){
    var _user = {};
    var interfaz = {
        addUser: function(user){
            _user = user;
        },
        getUser: function(){
            return _user;
        }

    }

    return interfaz;
});
```

> _user